# Is it possible to repeat the background strip inside the sprite image

Tags: image, html, css

I need to repeat the background image strip, which is from inside of the sprite image format. i have aligned the images in sprite in vertical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot repeat a part of a sprite image.

What you could do is use `repeat-x` to repeat the image on the horizontal axis, but your repeating image segment must have the same height as the element it is assigned to, and all other sprites present in that larger image must be above or below your repetitive segment. 
(Similarly, use `repeat-y` and place all your other sprites to the left and right of your background segment)

Your best option is to cut out and use the 5x5 pixels background from a separate image, which you can easily `repeat` over the entire element.

Comment: yeah u're correct George , thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Background-repeat:repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `background-repeat: repeat-y;` or `background-repeat: repeat-x;`